# How to add allowfullscreen to featherlight.js in the iframe?

Tags: featherlight.js

How can I add allowfullscreen to featherlight.js for a video?

The example on the http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/ website for the iFrame video has allowfullscreen on it, I just can't figure out how to add it to my own video url.

The format for adding the video URL I'm using is:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aqL9W4VhgoA" data-featherlight="iframe">link</a>
```

I can't figure out where to put the allowfullscreen since adding it to the URL doesn't work, I also tried this:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aqL9W4VhgoA" data-featherlight-allowfullscreen="true" data-featherlight="iframe">link</a>
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks!
Charles

Answer (score 0):

Either do like the example (have an hidden `<iframe>` already present on the page), or else use the `afterContent` callback to add the attribute.

Comment: can you point me to code where the aftercontent is added? I just want to add allowfullscreen but don't want to do the hide the iframe since it's on the homepage. Thanks so much!